Update a companies custom field in agilecrm via the PHP API
I know that this sounds dumb, but the github is very unclear about how to do this. The instructions are as follows:
2.4 Update properties of a company (partial update)
If updating custom field, make sure it should be present in the below link
https://{domain}.agilecrm.com/#custom-fields
$company_json = array(
  "id"=>"5695414665740288", //It is mandatory filed. Id of company
  "properties"=>array(
  array(
    "name"=>"name",
    "value"=>"test company",
    "type"=>"SYSTEM"
  ),
  array(
    "name"=>"url",
    "value"=>"https://www.test-company.org",
    "type"=>"SYSTEM"
    )
  )
);

$company_json = json_encode($company_json);
curl_wrap("contacts/edit-properties", $company_json, "PUT", "application/json");

Where am I supposed to put the #custom-fields code (if at all)?
I used the provided curl wrap code they provided, and I have tested it block by block. for example:
Working:
$company_json = array(
             "id"=>$lcID,
             "properties"=>array(
             array(
             "name"=>"address",
              "value"=> $formattedAddress,
              "type"=>"SYSTEM"
               
            )
            )
        );

Not working:
$company_json = array(
             "id"=>$lcID,
             "properties"=>array(
             array(
             "name"=>"address",
              "value"=> $formattedAddress,
              "type"=>"SYSTEM"
              ),
             array(
              "name"=>"last_address_check",
              "value"=> $lcCurrDateTime,
              "type"=>"CUSTOM"
              )
              )
            );


